# uiviewanimation works in ios 7 but gets clipped and offset in ios6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

working on moving my app to IOS7, but i'm having a uiviewanimation problem.

Everything works fine in IOS7, but when i use uiviewanimation to "flip" between two views, the view looks wrong during the transition, but fine after. It's higher up, and a part of the bottom of the view is clipped. See attached picture.

When the animation completes, the view "jumps" down to its correct position. I'm at a loss...

the code i use to flip my view is:

```
newView = [[LocationCrudViewController alloc] initWithNibName:THE_VIEW bundle:nil];
.....    
[UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:0.5
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                        animations:^ { self.window.rootViewController = newView; }
                        completion:nil];
```

Point worth noting - i used to do:

```
self.window addSubview:currentViewController.view];
```

as the view animation, and that worked, however i then got the warning message that Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch so i switched to the above code which, again, works fine in IOS7.

I'm reeeaaally hoping someone can help out here.

[image]

Comment: Thought I had the answer so I tried to run your code. But I got even worse result, it doesn't even flip, the view just expands to fill the screen with the code above. Hope someone can help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, here's what i ended up doing:

My views are defined as per normal (for me), no ios6/7 deltas are needed, in a nib with associated controllers.

I have created a "dummy" view, which takes up the entire screen but has no content.

In my application delegate, i create my dummy view and set it as root:

```
self.root = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:ROOT_VIEW_CONTROLLER bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = root;
```

I can then add and remove subviews as i see fit, like this:

```
[currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:0.5
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                        animations:^ {
                            [self.window addSubview:newViewController.view]; }
                        completion:nil];
```

This works great, and it makes my views go under the status bar in both IOS6 and IOS7, just as i want.

Hope this helps somebody.